# Error- Cannot find libev headers CentOS 6 Hitch install Varnish

Tags: centos6, varnish, epel

CentOS 6

I'm trying to install hitch to run with Varnish for HTTPS and one of the packages it needs is libev headers - hitch is not in the latest EPEL Repo as I keep being informed when trying to install so I managed to download extract and trying to install it manually - but getting when running ./configure --prefix=/opt/hitch

Error
configure: error: Cannot find libev headers.

Can someone explain how to fix this as Running sudo yum install libev-devel does not install as there is no package

I tried to install manually libev-devel but still the same error is coming up when trying to install hitch - I think it may be wrong version

Please can someone clarify which file and exact steps needed to install libev headers on CentOS 6

Comment: If you’re running CentOS 6 with an existing application you’ll still get security updates but for new features and deployments, please do yourself a favor and upgrade the OS to something recent. [CentOS 6 is scheduled to reach EOL in a couple of months](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#What_is_the_support_.27.27end_of_life.27.27_for_each_CentOS_release.3F)

Comment: You first need to update to a more current CentOS release.

Comment: We at Varnish Software are working on official Hitch packages. Keep an eye out on our website or social media for a release date. These packages will ensure a smooth install for Hitch, and guarantees updates.

Comment: thanks can you let me know if this for centos 6 aswell